# Generating AES-256 Private Key from user string

Tags: encryption, aes, sha-256

So I wish to encrypt a string using AES-256 and want to provide the user to specify the password for unlocking the string. I plan to use sha-256 to hash to users entered password and use this as the key. Is this secure? and is their a better way of doing this?

Edit: it would be nice if people left a comment about why they down-voted it.

Comment: No it is not secure. Yes there are better ways. Look at Argon and SCrypt.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thank you I didn't know about this I'm new to cryptography thanks

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson would you please mind and convert your comment to a (short) answer with relevant links perhaps?

Comment: related https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/how-secure-is-it-to-use-password-as-aes-key/22683#22683

Comment: @RichieFrame quite different ngl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a key derived from a password hash means someone could brute force this using either a known list of passwords or dictionary.

Since SHA-256 is quite fast, it's very easy to do with a moderate amount of computational power.

To better protect the key from such an attack, it is suggested to use a password derived from a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function).

Some examples of these include: [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).